# Android Gradle keyAlias variables stored in separate file

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing Android project relying on Jenkins CI. All the signing keys are stored in separate repository in encrypted gradle.properties file. In the project repository the gradle.properties file is tracked and (obviously) doesn't contain the keys.

Here is the example build.gradle signing part for the project's module:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
        storeFile file(KEYSTORE_PATH)
        storePassword KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
        keyPassword MOBILE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
```

My question is: how can I store those keys on my local development machine and being able to build the project **without** changing gradle.properties file and modifying build files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this one out. According to [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html), the configuration is applied in the following order:

> gradle.properties in project root directory.
>
> gradle.properties in GRADLE_USER_HOME directory.
>
> system properties, e.g. when -Dgradle.user.home is set on the command
>   line.

So all I had to do was to add custom gradle.properties file in gradle home directory (/USERNAME/.gradle/ on Mac)

Comment: Be carefull, configurations in other applications will be overriden as well

Comment: @LionelBriand You are correct, thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 0):

first create a file named `external.properties` at root project directory.

then check if this file exist

```
def externalPropertyFile = file("${rootProject.projectDir.path}${File.separator}external.properties")

if (!propertyFile.exist()) {
    throw new GradleException("external.property file doesn't exist")
}
```

verify if proprties exist in current context, if not load the property file

```
if (!rootProject.ext.has("externalProperties")) {
    rootProject.ext {
        externalProperties = new Properties()
        externalProperties.load(propertyFile.newReader())
    }
}
```

You can do the same check in signingConfigs and omit the release build if properties aren't available:

```
signingConfigs {
    if (rootProject.ext.has("externalProperties")) {
        release {
            keyAlias rootProject.externalProperties.KEY_ALIAS
            storeFile file(rootProject.externalProperties.KEYSTORE_PATH)
            storePassword rootProject.externalProperties.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyPassword rootProject.externalProperties.MOBILE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this requires modifying my build scripts.

Comment: @JanSlominski if you can't change properties nor script then you can't change gradle process. I suggest you to check the [Build and sign your app from command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually) section